# What is the best way to track customer id via google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The goal is to pass the customer id when I load the google-analytics tag. How to separate the loading of google analytics tag and sending the customer id to the tag without having it marked as double conversion
When I load via GTM in the header, I don't have that customer-id available from the back end code.

If I lazy load the tag with 4-sec time delay, google analytics will give me information that the customer spent 0 sec on the page instead of 4 secs

I tried lazy loading but it is giving me different information.
Is it possible to separate the two things

1. Loading Google analytics tag in the header
2. Sending customer id to google analytics

While doing this I want this transaction to be calculated as 1 conversion and not two conversions.

Expected result
1. Able to load GA tag in the header 
2. able to send customer details once it is available from the back end

Have these two steps marked as one transaction

Comment: What do you mean exactly by marking these two hits as one transaction/conversion? Do you have an Analytics goal set up for any of these hits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the pageview to Google Analytics, then when the userID is available, send it to Google Analytics with an event.

Set the goal only on the pageview of that page.